# IOS get image from document folder use full link

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsurl, nsdocumentdirectory

I have saved some images into document folder, after that, I used link full to get image.

`strImageName` is link full path to image.

```
    +(UIImageView *)getImage:(NSString*)strImageName showImage:(UIImageView*)showImage{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strImageName]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    showImage.image = image;
    return showImage;
}
```

But, it's get data = nil.

When I log, it's show:

```
Failed to read file, error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x8517ff0 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7EE5BEC1-0F60-461A-8B29-5F9B425ED1A6/Documents/emoji29.png, NSUnderlyingError=0x8517f70 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

I have research some ways, but it's not working for me.

How to I can resolve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No such file or directory" Error when creating directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602726/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-creating-directory)

Comment: have you tried appending the image name to the documents directory ? when you reinstall the app the application folder sometimes changes its name. 
    `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`
    
   `NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];`
 `NSString *imageName = [docDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/imageName"];`

Comment: Use the dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: method to find out why it's returning nil. The error will be returned in the NSError* pointer that you pass as arg of the method.

Comment: How to I can resolve this problem, I use full link into document folder to get image: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B4A07DB8-FD73-461E-86EE-24CA8A3F7855/Documents/emoji32.png

Answer (score 0):

`NSString *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image1" ofType:@"png"] isDirectory:NO];`

`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];`

Comment: add some description to your answer which make it more understandable or helpful for others